# Windows services not built from command prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, batch-file

I have the following command in my batch file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv" c:\work\test\test.sln /build debug
```

All my projects are that are part of the solution are built except the windows services projects.

I tried /project servicename.cfg and that did not work either.

Any ideas how to get the services built from a batch file?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use msbuild? I believe VS uses it under the hood. Is it built when you do that from UI?

Comment: This does not seem like a batch-file problem at all. Sound like you just do not know what commands to run to do what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, when building from UI, it builds the services as part of the solution.